# How to view where a post request is made from a form?

Tags: javascript, html

When I am bulding my HTML form I usually use

```
<from action="/postRoute" method="post">
```

to send a post request.

However, I was inspecting a form that I need to know the post request url of and I saw something like this:

```
<form action="index.cfm?fuseaction=security.login_check" method="post">
```

What does this mean? Is this the post request ulr as in

```
url/index.cfm?fuseaction=security.login_check
```

Why would it be written like this?

Comment: it's just a relative link, compared to your absolute address. it will resolve to whatever "folder" your page is hosted on.

Answer (score 0):

To be sure, try open chrome dev tools on network tab before you execute the request/submit form. Then you should try to submit and on network tab you should see the details about this request with full path and other necessary details.

Answer (score 0):

You're absolutely right. This funny-looking string is indeed the post URL of the form.

And this can happen due to a wide variety of reasons. Here, .cfm in the URL *might* refer to Coldfusion Markup (a type of web technology), indicating that the website you're inspecting uses Coldfusion behind the scenes.

Hope this clears things up. :)